# TinyMCE 4.9.x still not work in shadow dom. Is there any ideas how to solve it?

Tags: tinymce, polymer-1.0, web-component, shadow-dom

I try to initialize tinyMCE to element, which placed in shadowDOM. (polymer web-components), but it's not work.

The same example of situation i found here: https://embed.plnkr.co/WXtcz2GUpOhgrhWBTcAW/

Do you have any ideas, how to initialize tinyMCE 4.9.3 for element in shadowDOM?
(test on FireFox 65.0.2, Chrome 72.0.3626.121)

Comment: After a little search, I think TinyMCE does not support Shadow Dom. https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/pull/561

Comment: This is the answer from them: Hi Hakan,

Thanks for reaching out. My name is Bryan and I came across your enquiry.

I'm also not finding any documentation specific to your requirement. I may advise posting at our community forum. It's a good place for our open source users to seek out technical assistance. 

Curious, are you evaluating any Premium Plugins for TinyMCE?

Bryan Carmody
Business Development
650.292.9659 x801

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Put the TinyMCE `<textarea>` in the light DOM.
2. Insert it in the Shadow DOM by the help of a `<slot>` element.

```js
class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    const textarea = document.createElement('textarea')
    this.appendChild(textarea)
    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })
        .innerHTML=`<style>
                :host { outline: 5px solid blue ; display: inline-block }
            </style>
            <slot></slot>`
    tinymce.init({
      target: textarea
    })
  }  
}

customElements.define('my-element', MyElement)
```

```html
<script data-require="tinymce@4.4.3" data-semver="4.4.3" src="https://cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>

<my-element></my-element>
```

Comment: @artpolt thank you for the accepted answer, you can upvote if it helped :-)